# Is $\mu$ the renormalization or factorization scale in the DGLAP equations?

Tags: renormalization, quantum-chromodynamics, partons

The DGLAP equations read
$$\frac{\partial f_i(x,\mu^2)}{\partial\ln\mu^2}=\sum_j\int^1_x\frac{dz}{z}P_{ij}(z,\alpha_s(\mu^2))f_j\left(\frac{x}{z},\mu^2\right),$$
where the $f_i$ are the parton distribution functions (PDFs), $P_{ij}$ are the so-called splitting kernels and $x,z$ are longitudinal momentum fractions.

But what is $\mu$? In [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/0409313) on p.26 *John Collins* says it is the renormalisation scale, which enters the PDF via dimensional regularization. But I have already seen other authors claim that it is a factorization scale, e.g. [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/0703156) on p.2.

So, which one is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following [T. Plehn](https://arxiv.org/abs/0810.2281) (p.7) the UV-renormalisation introduces a dependence on the renormalisation scale $\mu$ and then the IR-regularisation introduces a further dependence on the factorisation scale $\mu_F$. However, one is free to choose $\mu$, such that one can set $\mu:=\mu_F$ [R. Brock et al.](https://inspirehep.net/files/a07787f3653b2a41945961ad44fbe926)(p.104), [D.E. Soper](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/9702203)(p.38), [W.K. Tung](https://doi.org/10.1142/9789812810458_0024) [[PDF](https://icecube.wisc.edu/%7Eaya/simulation/prompt/ref/pqcd-theory/IntroPqcd-long.pdf) (p.19)]. Hence, J.C. Collins' lack of mentioning the factorisation scale in most of his papers and most notably his book *Foundations of Perturbative QCD*.

Comment: This didn't answer the question really. It's really the factorization scale that enters the DGLAP equations, but we usually choose $\mu_F=\mu=Q$ where $Q$ is the photon virtuality.